# c++) why it occur overflow??? (type change problem)

Tags: c++

I am calculating the numbers to sqaure number
but its overflowed when the sqaure number is over the int range

```cpp
long long arr[1000000];
int c;
for(int i=2; i<1000000; i++)
{
   arr[c++] = i*i;
}
```

I am trying like this then solved

```cpp
long long arr[1000000];
int c;
for(long long i=2; i<1000000; i++)
{
    arr[c++] = i*i;
}
```

But i want to know why this is happen. Please help me.

Comment: once you calculate `i*i` with `int`s and then with `long long`. `long long` is wider than `int`

Comment: uh, you explained it yourself? `i*i` is bigger than what a int can hold for numbers where the result is bigger than 2147483647

Comment: Uninitialized local variables (like `c`) really *are* uninitialized. They will have an *indeterminate* value. And using indeterminate values in any way leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also, local variable (including arrays) are usually stored on the stack. The stack is a limited resource, on Linux the default stack for a process is 8 MiB. Which happens to be the size of your array `arr` as well. So the code won't even run. In short, when asking questions, please make sure you show us proper a [mre].

Comment: `i` is of type `int`, so calculating `i*i` gives a result of type `int`.  If that value exceeds what an `int` can represent, it is overflowed.   In the expression `arr[c++] = i*i`, `i*i` is still computed as an `int` (with overflow, if `i` is large enough) and the result is *then* promoted to `long long`.    There is no rule in the C++ standard that would cause `i*i` to be computed as `long long` in that circumstance.    And `c` is uninitialised, which is ANOTHER source of undefined behaviour (its initial value is indeterminate).

Answer (score 2):

When you multiply a `int` with another `int` it produces a `int` type value. Here, in your first code, you multiply `i*i`   **(1000000 * 1000000 = 1000000000000)** which is not in the `int` range but the `i` is a `int` type so the overflow occurs.